# Recursive loop to get the parent of an object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use the below function to get the parent object of a element.

```
'Recursive until the parent control is found
Public Function __GET_PARENT(ByVal current As Object, ByVal pType As Type)
    Dim nextParent As Object = current.Parent
    If Not nextParent Is Nothing AndAlso Not TypeOf nextParent Is pType Then Return __GET_PARENT(nextParent, pType)
    Return nextParent
End Function
```

For example, If I pass an object named textbox_1 as the current parameter and panel as the pType parameter for the above function it should return the actual panel object.

I get an error when comparing the TypeOf nextParent is pType, saying that pType is not defined.

Comment: With [TypeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx) you have to compare an object with a type. In your sample, you are comparing two objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather change Object to control and then add a loop to look through all the levels as follows:

```
Public Function __GET_PARENT(ByVal current As Control, ByVal pType As Type) As Control
    Dim parent As Control = current.Parent
    While parent IsNot Nothing
        If pType.IsAssignableFrom(parent.GetType()) Then
            Return parent
        End If

        parent = parent.Parent
    End While
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

My VB is a bit rusty but this should do the trick.

Otherwise you could use generics, so that your return type isn't object / control, but Panel or whatever you're looking for. Then you could do this:

```
Public Function __GET_PARENT(Of T As Control)(ByVal current As Control) As T
    Dim parent = current.Parent
    If (parent Is Nothing) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    If GetType(T).IsAssignableFrom(parent.GetType()) Then
        Return CType(parent, T)
    End If
    Return __GET_PARENT(Of T)(parent)
End Function
```

And then simply call it as follows:

```
Dim ctrl As Panel = __GET_PARENT(Of Panel)(Button1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I can't use a simple `If parent.GetType() = pType` because sometimes the parent.GetType() should = pType event if the parent is an inherit of pType. That is why I used TypeOf operator. can you help me out with an alternative solution.

Comment: @codeGEN: You can use the `IsSubClassOf` method for that. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Change `If parent.GetType() = pType` to `pType.IsAssignableFrom(parent.GetType())`. I've edited both code snippets in the answer above. That should do the trick now. Gotta run, enjoy the weekend :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Is` operator takes a type as the second parameter, not a `Type` object.

Get the type for the control and compare to the `Type` object:

```
... AndAlso nextParent.GetType() <> pType Then ...
```

Side note: Consider simpy using a loop rather than recursion for this.

#### Edit:

To also find parent controls that inherit from the type, you can use the [`IsSubclassOf` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
... AndAlso nextParent.GetType() <> pType AndAlso Not nextParent.GetType().IsSubclassOf(pType) Then ...
```

Comment: thanks for the side note @Guffa. Using a loop seems more clear to read than a recursion.